# Approving a message using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When on of the admin clicks an approve button its supposed to add the user_id of the person approving to a field in approval table

This is the button

```
 <?php echo anchor('admin/messages/approve/'.$message->id.'', 'Approve', 'class="btn btn-success"'); ?>
```

This is the approve function in Controller

```
public function approve($id) {

$data  = array(
  'first_approval'      =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')
 );


    $this->Message_model->approve($id, $data);


        //isset Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Your approval was send');

        //Redirect
        redirect('admin/messages');

}
```

This is the approve method inside the Model

```
public function approve($data) {

   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('approval');
   $this->db->join('messages', 'messages.id = approval.sms_id');

   $this->db->where('id', 'sms_id');
   $this->db->set('first_approval', $data);
   $this->db->update('approval');
}
```

I have sms_id, first_approval, second_approval and third_approval columns in my approval table but for now I'm just testing if I can put session->user_id in the column 'first_approval'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `approve` method as following in MODEL

```
public function approve($id, $data) {
   $this->db->where('sms_id', $id);
   $this->db->update('approval',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below view model and controller

View

```
 <?php echo anchor('admin/messages/approve/'.$message->id.'', 'Approve', 'class="btn btn-success"'); ?>
```

Controller

```
class Messages extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->load->model('message_model');
  }
  function approve(){
      $id = $this->uri->segment(3); //Get message id
      $data  = array(
         'first_approval'      =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id')
      );

      $res = $this->Message_model->approve($id, $data);

      if($res >0){
        //Redirect
        redirect('admin/messages');
      }else{
       //some error accured 
      }
  }
}
```

Model

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Message_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database(); //If database not set in autoload
    }

   public function approve($id, $data) {
       $this->db->where('sms_id', $id);
       return $this->db->update('approval',$data); //If table update return no of rows update
   }

}
```